# A lot of upvotes in a single day?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, up-votes, serial-voting

I know someone upvoted for [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4146975/how-can-you-simplify-verify-this-solution-for-int-0-25991-q-1x-x-xdx/4239642#4239642), but someone new did it. Here is my strange string of upvotes which I am sure has been asked about, but would like to know if it is “real reputation”:
[image]

I woke up today seeing that I somehow had what seemed like “serial upvotes”. This happened the night, in EST time, when I posted [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4232284/integral-forms-of-a-general-tetration-power-tower-integral-solution-sum-lim). It seems like someone, or a group of people went into my account and upvoted. Are these votes fairly gotten or not?

Comment: Yea it's real. Some bountied questions pick up steam very quickly. You even got a [tweet](https://twitter.com/StackMath/status/1435618963048878081) from the stack_math twitter bot!

Comment: I suggest you care less about it. If most of the votes comes from one user, likely it will be reverted soon. If it is not, so be it.

Comment: I don't think you've ever had your question/answer go into the hot network queue, possibly because of the kind of question you frequent (which involves integrals and hence a lot of MathJax terminology, which is inaccessible to a super-general population). I had two questions go into the hot network queue a long time ago, and I had so many up votes that day , probably about 40+. I couldn't believe it, and none of those votes were reversed, so enjoy the reputation, I suppose!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon If you look, the reputation is for mixed questions, so which one became a hot question?

Comment: @TymaGaidash None of them became a HNQ, as far as I remember. They will have appeared to the left of the screen under "HNQ" sometime yesterday, but I don't recall any of them over there. So the votes aren't HNQ votes, they are from someone who saw your posts as a normal visitor (versus those on other sites who saw only your question under the HNQ and clicked on it) on MSE and liked them, which is also really nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like [@ArcticChar](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/629362/arctic-char) wrote:

> You should stop worrying about these votes. If the system detects them as serial voting those would be reverted and if these upvote not reverted then have fun. These are the upvotes you earned from your hard work.